# How to use HTML Helper or call the initialize() in Cell?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

How to/Can I use HTML Helper/initialize() in Cell CakePHP 3.0?

**/src/View/Cell/NavCell.php**

```
namespace App\View\Cell;

use Cake\View\Cell;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\View\Helper\HtmlHelper;

class NavCell extends Cell
{
    public function initialize() {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadHelper('Html');  
    }

    public function display() {
    }
}
```

**/src/Template/Cell/Nav/display.ctp**

```
<?php $this->Html->script('script', ['block' => 'scriptBottom']); ?>
```

Comment: Read the documentation  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html

Comment: Hi Suraj, is for cakephp 3.0 and not for cakephp 2.0.

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#linking-to-javascript-files  http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.View.Helper.HtmlHelper.html  check this

Comment: initialize the helper class then you will be able to call it  in your view files

Comment: Suraj, I've tried your method before and updated my code above. It not calling(embedding) the script.

Answer (score 3):

Cells do neither have an `initialize()`, nor a `loadHelper()` method, you can't just throw code together and hope that it works. Always have a look in Cookbook and the API docs first, if necessary check the source code.

Cells supply a `$helpers` property where you can define the helpers to use/load.

**[API > \Cake\View\Cell::$helpers](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.View.Cell.html#$helpers)**

```
class NavCell extends Cell
{
    public $helpers = [
        'Html'
    ];

    // ...
}
```

However this shouldn't even be necessary in case you don't want to apply any configuration, as views do lazy load possible helpers when non existent properties are being accessed,

- **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/View/View.php#L742**
- **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/View/HelperRegistry.php#L60**

ie using `$this->Html->script()` in a cell would work out of the box.

It should also be noted that, as mentioned (though anything but detailed) in the API docs, `$helpers` is one of the properties that is being fed with the corresponding properties value of the class that makes use of `\Cake\View\CellTrait`, ie the helpers config that is set for the view (wich in turn stems from the corresponding controller) where you are calling `$this->cell()` is being copied to the cell.

### tl;dr - You cannot define/access blocks outside of the cell scope

However, cells are using separate view class instances, so the blocks that you define/access in your cell, do not affect the view that is used by other templates like for example layouts!